# highcharts: Set same spacing between bars

Tags: highcharts, angular7

I have a chart, where the charts are not aligned in a straight line. How can i make them align.
In the below chart there are three charts in the first chart from left there is only result, in the second there are two results, and in the third chart (right) has there results. 
The first has only one result so its showing in the middle of the graph, is there any option i can set where all the three gets aligned in a straight line.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/

[Image of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QtLS.png)

I tried setting the empty values to zero, that doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because points in Highcharts bar chart are equally placed on the plot area.

As a workaround, you can set null points like that:

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  ...
  series: [{
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [
        null,
      null,
        234
    ]
  }],
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  ...
  series: [{
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [
        null,
      439,
      525
    ]
  }],
});

Highcharts.chart('container3', {
  ...
  series: [{
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      346
    ]
  }],
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yc8grdeL/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed same kind of solution..I pushed empty values for solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer was helpful for you please upvote or mark it as a correct one, thanks.